# Require help in calling a Java program from a batch file

Tags: java, postgresql, batch-file, jdbc

I have a very simple Java program that connects to a PostgreSQL database to find if there are any databases by a specific naming pattern. When I find them I'm trying to delete them through the Java JDBC code. The Java code works fine when I manually run it, but what I'm trying to achieve is to automate this Java call through a batch file.

Can anyone throw any light on this? It's been frustratingly long that I'm struggling to find a solution for this.

My Java Code:

```
public class CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            String line;
            RandomAccessFile batchFile = new RandomAccessFile("C:/batch.sql", "rw");
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "Welcome12!");
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select datname from pg_database where datname like 'sample_db%';");

            while (rs.next()) {
                batchFile.writeBytes("DROP DATABASE " + rs.getString("datname") + ";\n");
                System.out.println(rs.getString("datname"));
            }

            Process batchProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql -h localhost -U postgres -f C:/batch.sql");
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(batchProcess.getInputStream()));
            if(batchFile.length()!= 0) {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            batchFile.close();
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught: " + exception);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlexception) {
                sqlexception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Batch file script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if not defined JAVA_HOME    goto :NoJavaFound

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "%~dp0\deletedb.jar;%~dp0\postgresql-9.4.1207.jar;" connect.postgresql.CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs
goto :end

:NoJavaFound
echo JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
goto :end

:end
endlocal
```

I have both the jar file (my Java code, shown above) and the batch script file on the Desktop (same folder) and attempting to run - but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`, as my java code is missing the PostgreSQL jdbc driver. I've tried to add that as a parameter in multiple ways, but nothing works.

Error details:

```
C:\Users\pavan>C:\Users\pbonda\Desktop\deletedb.bat
Exception caught: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at connect.postgresql.CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs.main(CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at connect.postgresql.CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs.main(CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp  "%~dp0\postgresql-9.4.1207.jar;%~dp0\deletedb.jar" connect.postgresql.CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the following error now: `Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\pavan\Desktop\\deletedb.jar;`

Answer (score 3):

When calling java with an executable jar, the classpath provided to the java command is ignored.

You should either :

- explicitly call the target class, with your jar in the classPath (i.e. `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp "%~dp0\deletedb.jar;%~dp0\postgresql-9.4.1207.jar;" connect.postgresql.CreateBatchToCleanNamedDBs`)
- specify the jar's classpath dependencies in its MANIFEST.MF file as well as its main class ; then you can execute the jar with `java -jar`. See this [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)
- <s>add the postgresql jar into the your current jre's extentions library directory, or in the global extentions library directory. See this [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)</s> [Deprecated in JavaSE 8, dropped in JavaSE9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under)

Comment: Aaron, First option that you've mentioned is exactly what I'm doing right now. For the second one to work, how or what needs to be added - I mean what jars are you talking about to be added to the manifest.mf file?

Comment: @BPavanKumar are you sure this is what you currently do? If so, you should edit your posted batch file, it is currently incorrect, using `-jar` where it should use `-cp`. For the second solution I'll post a link to some documentation, but I'm pretty sure the first one is better suited to your needs. Oh and I just thought of a third solution that might be a good alternative, I'll add that too.

Comment: There, I can't think of anything else. I would recommend the third solution in dev for its flexibility and one of the two first for production, depending on how much you control the environment it will be run on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron, mistake from my side... Realized that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Be aware that the third option (extension mechanism) is deprecated in Java 8 and is slated to be dropped from Java 9. Details [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under).

Comment: @GordThompson thanks, I didn't know that ! I edited my post to reflect that.